# Splitting a string into an array of floats and characters

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex

We are working with a string that can contain integers, floats and characters.

Example:

> .12A1.3B.5CD

I want to take that string and turn it into an array of numbers and characters that looks like

> [.12,A,1.3,B,.5,C,0,D]

(when there is no number in front of the letter, it is assumed to be a 0)

I have tried different regex combinations and can't get any to work like:

```
str.match(/[a-zA-Z]+?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+/g)
```

but it gives me the result of:

> ["12", "A", "1", "3", "B", "5", "CD"]

chopping off the decimal point and not separating the "D" to "0,D"

Again the desired result is [.12,A,1.3,B,.5,C,0,D].

Any guesses?

Comment: I would recommend you look at the [`parseFloat()`](https://www.w3schools.com/JSREF/jsref_parsefloat.asp) and [`parseInt()`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parseint.asp) functions.

Comment: once again I see that the most slow solution was accepted and "overclicked". Sad but true ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could replace the missing zeros and match the parts. Later map the value after checking for number or string.

```js
var string ='.12A1.3B.5CD',
    array = string
        .replace(/((^|[a-z])(?=\.))|([a-z](?=[a-z]))/gi, '$&0')
        .match(/[.0-9]+|[a-z]/gi)
        .map(v => v == +v ? +v : v);

console.log(array);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 3):

You can add a zero after each letter if it is followed by another letter and then split on letters:

```js
var s = ".12A1.3B.5CD";

console.log(
  s.replace(/([a-z])(?=[a-z])/gi, "$1"+"0").split(/([a-z])/i).filter(x => x != "")
)
```

Comment: the only thing that remains for your approach is to cast numeric strings to numbers. In general, your approach seems to be the fastest

Answer (score 1):

With `String.match()`, `Array.reduce()` and `isNaN()` functions:

```js
var s = '.12A1.3B.5CD', prev,
    result = s.match(/(\d*\.)?\d+|[a-zA-Z]/g).reduce(function(a, v){
        v = +v || v;
        if (a.length > 1 && +v !== v && isNaN(prev)) a.push(0);
        a.push(v);
        prev = v;
        return a;
    }, []);

console.log(result)
```

"Speed" comparison:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

`str.match(\([a-zA-Z]|[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+)\g)`

then using javascript you should insert a 0 into the array between consecutive letters.

A good website to check out regex's: https://regex101.com/r/vhnv2M/1

Comment: It still doesn't insert `0` between `C` and `D`. And the syntax is wrong (\ instead of /).